# UK citizen travelling on ESTA program wants to make a side trip to Caribbean while in USA

Tags: uk-citizens, caribbean, esta

My brother is a regular visitor from UK to USA and stays with me in NYC. We always take side trips maybe to Canada, Bermuda, Costa Rica etc and my question is will we be allowed a trip to Barbados for 3 or 4 days which is in the Caribbean but quite far away.

Comment: Why wouldn't you? Is there something unusual about your brother's immigration status?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Just to make sure:  What is your question?  Will he be allowed back?  Can he just go to Barbados?  Will it count against his ESTA?  Can you please clarify.

Comment: I think there are strict restrictions on Visa Waiver to the USA. To use it you have to be entering from a Visa Waiver country, one can however make side trips to nearby places such as Canada and Mexico for example. I think a visa would be required if you travel outside the restricted area but I am not sure. The US consulate in Barbados advises " We strongly urge visitors to this region to apply for U.S. visas in their country of residence. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @user6784, that's wrong. You do not need to enter from a Visa Waiver country - you simply need to be eligible for it by citizenship and have pre-arranged the ESTA. See the official write-up here for more information: http://travel.state.gov/visa/temp/without/without_1990.html.

Comment: @user6784. As Andrew Ferrier pointed out that's wrong. The sentence you quote means that if you **need** to apply for a US visa, you should do that in your home country and not in Barbados. But if you are eligible for ESTA, you don't need to apply for a US visa to begin with, so this sentence doesn't apply to you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, should be fine. He will enter the U.S. under the Visa Waiver Program. This allows travel for up to 90 days and is multiple entry.

Comment: I cannot find a direct answer in the government websites but the US consulate in Barbados advises " We strongly urge visitors to this region to apply for U.S. visas in their country of residence" That is different from ESTA> Thanks for the input.

Comment: Yes, but he won't be getting a visa. He is from an eligible  Visa Waiver Program country. ESTA is just the authorization for the Visa Waiver Program.

Answer (score 2):

If he's traveling on Visa Waiver Program under [ESTA](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1126/session/L3NpZC84SDN5eHNxbA%3D%3D) you have approval to enter for 2 years.  When going to Barbados the 90 days count [doesn't stop](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/194/~/visa-waiver-program---eligible-countries) so it should be kept in mind

Comment: The US consulate in Barbados advises " We strongly urge visitors to this region to apply for U.S. visas in their country of residence" So I think he would require a visa to be on the safe side. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @user6784 If you already have ESTA under which you have entered US then you won't need to reapply.  Now if Barbados is the intermediate stop on his way to the US then yes it's better to apply from the UK.